# How to add content picker filed in Form in a custom Orchard Workflow activity

Tags: orchardcms

I have created an a custom Orchard Workflow activity, this activity allows user to select a content Item from already created contents in Admin UI. Now to allow selection of content Item I want to use content picker field in Activity Form. But I noticed that Activity forms use only basic shapes, I could not find any way to create a form that can use already crated custom fields or allows building of form using custom editor shape.

I have been able to achieve something using select list (like below), But I need a way to add content picker field to form or better way to filter content items in the form.

```
 context.Form("SendContentAsAttachement", factory =>
        {
            var shape = (dynamic)factory;
            var f = shape.Form(
            Id: "SendContentAsAttachement",
            _ContentList: shape.SelectList(
                Id: "contentId", Name: "contentId",
                Title: T("Response to user message"),
                Description: T("Please select a content to send to user")));

            var list = _contentManager.Query().ForType(new[] { "Type1", "type2", "type3", "type4"}).List().Select(item => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = item.Id.ToString(),
                Text = string.Format("[{0}]{1}", item.TypeDefinition.DisplayName, item.As<TitlePart>().Title)
            });

            foreach (var item in list)
                f._ContentList.Add(item);

            return f;
        });
```